# Como imprimo dentro de un array vacío otro array lleno de objetos que he importado exitosamente desde un json ? Gracias!

Tags: array, json, imprimir

```
//tengo este primer array vacío, aquí quiero meter el array que estoy trayendo del json.

const arrayVacio = [];  

//aquí hago fetch del array de json

fetch("./nuevoArrayDeObjetos.json")

.then(resp => resp.json())

.then(data => console.log(data))

//ahora quiero ponerlo dentro del "arrayVacío" del inicio.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tenés que llamar al método push desde tu array vacío, y pasarle como parámetro lo que quieras insertarle (no tiene que ser necesariamente un array).

```js
let arrayVacio = []
const array = [1,2,3,4,5]

arrayVacio.push(array);

console.log(arrayVacio)
```

Entonces vos tendrias que hacer

```
fetch("./nuevoArrayDeObjetos.json")

.then(resp => resp.json())

.then(data => arrayVacio.push(data))
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo que tu me recomiendas es lo primero que había intentado pero no me funciona. El console.log me muestra correctamente el array importado pero el array vacío se mantiene igual de vacío.

Comment: Allí encontré que el "arrayVacio" no está vacío, sinó que incorporó otro array dentro en vez de incorporar los objetos limpios.

Comment: Gracias Agustín, Ahora tengo que ver como resuelvo pushear solo los objetos y no la estructura del array traido del json, eso creo.

Comment: Resuelto, Gracias Agustin. El tercer .then no levanta data si no borro antes el segundo. Hay que borrar el .then del console log para reemplazarlo por el .then que alimenta el arrayVacio.

Comment: @RafaelKetelhohn recien leo todo, me alegro que funcione, sospechaba que el console debia ser borrado, edito la respuesta para no confundir a nadie. Saludos